# How can I get the html code of the Dom element?

Tags: htmlunit

I use the class name to find the DomElement, how can I find the html code of that class using that DomElement or any other way?

```
DomElement htmlEl = currentPage.querySelector(".next");
```

Thank you.

Comment: html code of class?? or the element to which the css class is applied?

Comment: Finally, I find the method which is "String temp = htmlEl.AsXML()". The problem is solved.